# Can't echo html <form> with $var using POST

Tags: php

new to php here so i apologize if the solution is super simple. I'm working on a password reset page, it will be the page the user lands on after clicking the email with the token. the issue is the form is not sending the value of $token, its just sending the string.

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["token"])) {

    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "USER", "PASSWORD", "USERDB");

    $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET["email"]);
    $token = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET["token"]);

    $data = $connection->query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_token='$token'");

        if ($data->num_rows > 0) {

            echo '<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Change Password</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="reset">
    <h1>Password reset</h1>
            <form action="anotherpage.php" method="POST">
     <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
     <input type="hidden" name="token" value="$token">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Update">

</form>

</body>
</html>';

        }   else {


            echo "Please check your link!";
        }





    }   else {

        header("Location: ../");
        exit();
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection

Comment: and value of `$_GET['token']` should be a string?

Comment: What's the link that you send the user look like?

Comment: you need to use double quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an advice... don't echo the htmltags... Is not a good practice... Instead of echo you can do that. And about the token issue will be fixed like this.

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["token"])) {

    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "USER", "PASSWORD", "USERDB");

    $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET["email"]);
    $token = $connection->real_escape_string($_GET["token"]);

    $data = $connection->query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_token='$token'");

        if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        ?>

<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Change Password</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="reset">
    <h1>Password reset</h1>
            <form action="anotherpage.php" method="POST">
     <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
     <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Update">

</form>

</body>
</html>
<?php

        }   else {


            echo "Please check your link!";
        }





    }   else {

        header("Location: ../");
        exit();
    }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sending the string `$token` because PHP will not parse variables in single quote (`'`). You must use double quote (`"`) and then escape the other double quotes (using `\`) or use single quotes in your echoed code. You could also use

`<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$token.'">`

While the above would work, I recommend you to send the form code without the echo.